# Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation

When I try to install Tensorflow this message appears. I use the latest version of python and pip.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\julia\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\com_github_grpc_grpc\\src\\core\\ext\\filters\\client_channel\\lb_policy\\grpclb\\client_load_reporting_filter.h'
```

It appears on all the older versions of Tensorflow. On the newest release appears this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.2.0
```

Answer (score 9):

Try following this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/.

Comment: The issue is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, only deleting manually the "leftovers" of the package in the environment directory fixed this problem.
path : ... "\venv\Lib\site-packages\ {package name}"
make sure you backup before deleting any file.

Answer (score 2):

I did a

```
pip cache purge
```

then

```
pip install <name>
```

worked

Comment: Does Not work with Linux Mint