# Tensorflow will not install on my desktop due to an os error

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pip

When I try to run pip install tensorflow on my vscode environment, it downloads everything fine, but when it comes to installing, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\The Dragon Of Light\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\tensorboard_plugin_wit\\_vendor\\tensorflow_serving\\sources\\storage_path\\file_system_storage_path_source_pb2.py'
```

I have tried a handful of things and I am still stuck.
I have already set LongPathsEnabled to 1.

Comment: Did you copy and paste that path into a file explorer window?

Comment: I did attempt to look for it manually and it seemed as if it literally doesn't exist on my pc. I tried installing that file manually (based on the online sourcecode) and through pip, however it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Some people others have run across [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980952/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672519/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno2-no-such-file-or-directory). It looks like the 260 Characters' limitation of the path in windows caused it. You can refer to [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/) to know how to adjust the limitation.

Comment: I already have that done on my machine, and i have triple checked that it was indeed set to 1, so unfortunately that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use below link to install and then upgrade it if you need higher version for the same

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP shouldn't try to install a Mac version of TensorFlow on an obviously Windows machine.